# Get lifecycle of UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, lifecycle, background-task

I'm creating an in-process UWP App Service, and another (desktop) client program that communicates with the app via the app service. The client program wants to know whether the UWP app is currently running (in the foreground), was already running in the background *before* the desktop app opened the `AppServiceConnection`, was suspended, or wasn't running at all. In other words, the app needs to be able to convey, through the app service, where it was in its [lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).

Is there any way to programmatically detect an app's lifecycle state, other than implementing my own state variable that I update whenever one of the relevant events is raised? It seems like it should be possible, but I can't find an API for it. Obviously it will never tell you that you are currently suspended or not running, but being able to tell the difference between "suspended except for this app service task" and "actively running in the foreground" would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> The client program wants to know whether the UWP app is currently running (in the foreground), was already running in the background before the desktop app opened the AppServiceConnection

Before the desktop app opened the `AppServiceConnection` connection, the client should not be able to communicate with the app service provider since the UWP app is sandbox. Get the current status for the app service provider inside it has no use for the client app. If the client desktop app is .NET Framework, you may try to use [`Process.Responding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get the service provider process status. For example,if `Process.Responding` is true then the service provider is "actively running in the foreground", if it is false, the provider should be suspended, if just cannot find the provider process, it should be terminated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
       if (process.ProcessName == "AppServicesProvider")
            Console.WriteLine("Process Name: {0}, Responding: {1}", process.ProcessName, process.Responding);
    } 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

> In other words, the app needs to be able to convey, through the app service, where it was in its lifecycle.

If you mean though the app service, the way you mentioned that store a state inside the [app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) when the execution state of the app is change should work well. It seems like you don't want to use it but actually the state matching event handle triggered indicate that the execution state of the app is changed.

```
private async void App_Suspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    SuspendingDeferral deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    localSettings.Values["currentlife"] = "Suspended";
    deferral.Complete();
}
private async void OnAppServiceRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Object value = localSettings.Values["currentlife"];
    try
    {
        var input = args.Request.Message; 
        //Create the response
        var result = new ValueSet(); 
        result.Add("result", value);
        //Send the response
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(result);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Complete the message deferral so the platform knows we're done responding
        messageDeferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: The desktop app in question is a background process that is included in the UWP app bundle via desktop bridge. It is a long-running process that can both start before the app does (via launch-at-Windows-login) and persist after the app closes. Some of the messages the desktop app might send the UWP app only make sense to send if the UWP app is already running, and not if it's suspended or hasn't launched yet.